# R-package development: Documenting and exporting functions with non-syntactic names

Tags: r, roxygen2

I'm writing a package (called `pac`) where I have a function with a non-syntactic name (called `+f`). I'm unable to correctly document and export this function.

Here's a reproducible example:

```
library(devtools)
setwd("~/yourpath")
create("pac")
```

Save the following function definition along with its documentation in `pac/R/+f.R`

```
#' Add two objects
#' 
#' @name `+f`
#' 
#' @param x an object
#' @param y an object
#' @return A sum
#' @export
`+f`<- function(x, y) {x + y}
```

Then run

```
document()
load_all()
`+f`(2, 2)
```

Which produces the output

```
> document()
Updating pac documentation
Loading pac
Writing NAMESPACE
Writing tick-plus-f-tick.Rd
> load_all()
Loading pac
Warning message:
In setup_ns_exports(path, export_all, export_imports) :
  Objects listed as exports, but not present in namespace: +f
> `+f`(2, 2)
Error in `+f`(2, 2) : could not find function "+f"
```

As you can see, the function `` `+f` `` is not exported correctly, even though the `NAMESPACE`-file does have the following line:

```
 export(`+f`)
```

On the other hand, since the documentation file `pac/man/tick-plus-f-tick.Rd` exists, I am able to display it by calling `` ?"`+f`" ``.

**How can I define and document a function with a non-syntactic name in a package?** What's going on in the above example? Why isn't the function available when `pac` is loaded, even though the `NAMESPACE`-file includes an export-statement?

Comment: I don't quite understand why you would want to name your function that.  Are you just trying to add a new method for `+`?

Comment: Writing R extensions 1.5.1 regarding the NAMESPACE file: "Note that variable names may be quoted, and reserved words and non-standard names such as [<-.fractions must be." Find out how you get roxygen2 to put quotes around the function name within `export`.

Comment: Possibly as simple as `@export "+f"`?

Comment: @Roland Thank you for your helpful suggestion. That was what I was trying with the `@name` tag. Whatever I write after `@name` shows up in the `export` statement in the `NAMESPACE`-file. I've now also tried variations using the `@export` tag, without any luck so far.

Comment: Have you tried `@export "+f"`? AFAIU, `@name` is an Rd-tag and not a NAMESPACE-tag. Since your issue is with exporting, an Rd-tag won't help.

Comment: I can't imagine a valid reason for having a function named `+f` in a package.